# Create JavaScript with Umbraco

Tags: javascript, umbraco

Do you know if there is a way to create a javascript or PHP file in Umbraco?

By this I mean that I would like to have the user populate fields in the same was as creating a page, but for it to output as .js or .php rather than the usual .aspx

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you couldn't; you could use a controller to output as pretty much anything by setting the mime-type.

I'd be wondering though what your use-case for generating PHP files would be though; the server would still need to process the PHP script somehow; which may not be a trivial task (unless you just want to generate the PHP file for download/display the code) as it isn't client-side script at all.

JavaScript on the other hand is entirely a different matter - as it's processed client-side you could just point the browser at a url that happens to deliver the generated JavaScript. You could even render the JavaScript out from a WebApi end-point and the browser client would quite happily consume it.